Get historical futures data on VIX using TWS API
When I specify this expired futures contract and the reqHistoricalData function, i am getting the results as expected:
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = "VIX"
contract.secType = "FUT"
contract.exchange = "CFE"
contract.currency = "USD"
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20240515"
contract.multiplier = "1000"
contract.includeExpired = True

I use the below to get past history:
app.reqHistoricalData(1, contract, "", "2 M", "1 day", "BID_ASK", 0, 1, False, [])

Then, i try to get past history of another expired contract. The only change is this:
contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20240320"

I am then receiving the below error:
"ERROR 1 162 Historical Market Data Service error message:HMDS query returned no data: VXH4@CFE Bid"
I tried all contracts that are not expired, and my quote always returns the data. But when i use expired contracts, some of them work, and some of them aren't.
Can someone please suggest a solution?
